# Parent-child communication via pipes in C

Tags: c

I am trying to get a parent process to accept user input for 4 integer variables (a, b, c, and x) and pipe them to the child process. The child process evaluates ax^2 + bx + c and pipes the result r to the parent, which displays it.

With the code I have now, any input results in a result of 1. The behavior of the print statements make me think only x is getting read, but even when I try to but x*x into r I don't get the right solution. What could I be doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#define PIPE_INPUT 0 
#define PIPE_OUTPUT 1 
#define INDENT 20 

void testError(int err, const char * str){ 
if ( err < 0 ){ 
    perror(str); 
exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
}
} 

int main(){ 

int fd_toChild[2]; 
int fd_toParent[2]; 

int buff[20];

pid_t pid; 

testError( pipe(fd_toChild), "pipe" ); 
testError( pipe(fd_toParent), "pipe" ); 
testError( pid = fork(), "fork" ); 

int a; 
int b; 
int c; 
int x; 
int r; 

if (pid > 0){     
    // this is the parent 


    int status;

    while(1){ 

        close( fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT] ); 
        close( fd_toParent[PIPE_OUTPUT] ); 


        printf("This program will evaluate a polynomial a(x^2) + bx + c. \n"); 
        printf("Please input an integer value for a: "); 
        scanf("%d", &a); 
        write(fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT], &a, sizeof(a)); 

        printf("Parent writes value %d to a \n", a); 
        printf("Please input an integer value for b: "); 
        scanf("%d", &b); 
        write(fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT], &b, sizeof(b)); 
        printf("Parent writes value %d to b \n", b); 

        printf("Please input an integer value for c: "); 
        scanf("%d", &c); 
        write(fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT], &c, sizeof(c)); 
        printf("Parent writes value %d to c \n", c); 

        printf("Please input an integer value for x: "); 
        scanf("%d", &x); 
        write(fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT], &x, sizeof(x)); 
        printf("Parent writes value %d to x \n", x); 

        close( fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT] ); 
        close( fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT] ); 

        read(fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT], buff, sizeof(r)); 

        pid = wait(&status); 

        fprintf(stdout, "Parent received back the result %d.\n", r); 
        printf("The polynomial evaluates to %d \n", r); 

        close( fd_toParent[PIPE_OUTPUT] ); 

        break;
    }
} 

else{ 
    // this is child 

    close( fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT] ); 
    close( fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT] ); 

    while(1){ 
        close( fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT] ); 
        close( fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT] ); 

        read(fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT], buff, sizeof(a)); 
        printf("Child reads value %d from a \n", a); 

        read(fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT], buff, sizeof(b)); 
        printf("Child reads value %d from b \n", b); 

        read(fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT], buff, sizeof(c)); 
        printf("Child reads value %d from c \n", c); 

        read(fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT], buff, sizeof(x)); 
        printf("Child reads value %d from x \n", x); r = a * x * x + b * x + c; 
        printf("x is %d", x); printf("r is %d", r); 

        write(fd_toParent[PIPE_OUTPUT], buff, sizeof(r)); 
        fprintf(stdout, "%*sChild is all done\n", INDENT, ""); 
        close( fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT] ); 

    } 
} 
return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Comment: You're doing to much closing. Parent process: you first close `fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT]` and immediately after that you try to read from it. Child process: in the end of loop, you close `fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT]` meaning that all further iterations of loop won't work as expected. All such types of errors would be easy to spot if you checked read/write return codes.

Comment: Your code as is above has other issues too.  @gudok is correct about closing the `pipe` but you also read into `buff` but try to print out from your other uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things that are throwing off your program here.  One issue was already pointed out by @gudok, where you close the `fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT]` and then attempt to read from it immediately after:

```
close( fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT] ); 
close( fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT] ); 
// just closed on the preceding line
read(fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT], buff, sizeof(r));
```

One other issue is in the child-process where you're trying to `read` in the values to operate on in the calculation:

```
read(fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT], buff, sizeof(a)); 
printf("Child reads value %d from a \n", a);
```

Here you pass the `buff` as your `read` buffer and then you try to operate/print from `a`.  This leaves `a` uninitialized, this would explain why you are just getting zero's back out when printing.  Instead you could use the address-of operator `&` of your coefficient variables:

```
read(fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT], &a, sizeof(a));
```

This goes for `b`, `c`, and `x` too.

And also when attempting to print out the result in the parent:

```
read(fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT], buff, sizeof(r)); 

pid = wait(&status); 

fprintf(stdout, "Parent received back the result %d.\n", r); 
printf("The polynomial evaluates to %d \n", r); 

close( fd_toParent[PIPE_OUTPUT] );
```

The line `read(fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT], buff, sizeof(r));` you're passing in `buff` but printing out `printf(The polynomial evaluates to %d \n", r)` you print `r` which is uninitialized inside of the parent-process.

You also have been enclosing the majority of your logic inside of a `while(1)` loop.  This won't affect the end result of the program because of the `break` in the parent-process but if you alter the parent-process loop the repeated calls to `close` would shutdown all ends of the pipes.

```
while(1){
    ....
    close( fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT] ); 
    close( fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT] );
}
```

Without the `break` your pipe won't be of any use.

I made several edits to show a working version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 

#define PIPE_INPUT 0 
#define PIPE_OUTPUT 1 
#define INDENT 20 


void testError(int err, const char * str)
{ 
    if (err < 0) {
        perror(str); 
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    int fd_toChild[2], fd_toParent[2], buff;
    pid_t pid; 

    testError( pipe(fd_toChild), "pipe" ); 
    testError( pipe(fd_toParent), "pipe" ); 
    testError( pid = fork(), "fork" ); 

    int a, b, c, x, r; 

    if (pid > 0){     
        // this is the parent 

        int status;

        close( fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT] ); 
        close( fd_toParent[PIPE_OUTPUT] ); 

        printf("This program will evaluate a polynomial a(x^2) + bx + c. \n"); 
        printf("Please input an integer value for a: "); 
        scanf("%d", &a); 
        write(fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT], &a, sizeof(a)); 

        printf("Parent writes value %d to a \n", a); 
        sleep(1);
        printf("Please input an integer value for b: "); 
        scanf("%d", &b); 
        write(fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT], &b, sizeof(b)); 
        printf("Parent writes value %d to b \n", b); 
        sleep(1);
        printf("Please input an integer value for c: "); 
        scanf("%d", &c); 
        write(fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT], &c, sizeof(c)); 
        printf("Parent writes value %d to c \n", c); 
        sleep(1);
        printf("Please input an integer value for x: "); 
        scanf("%d", &x); 
        write(fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT], &x, sizeof(x)); 
        printf("Parent writes value %d to x \n", x); 
        sleep(1);
        // XXX you close then attempt to read from it
        //close( fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT] ); 

        read(fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT], &buff, sizeof(buff)); 

        pid = wait(&status); 
        // XXX Here you are showing the results as your uninitialized variable "r"
        fprintf(stdout, "Parent received back the result %d.\n", buff); 
        printf("The polynomial evaluates to %d \n", buff); 

        close( fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT] ); 
        close( fd_toParent[PIPE_OUTPUT] ); 
    } else { 
        // this is child 

        close( fd_toChild[PIPE_OUTPUT] ); 
        close( fd_toParent[PIPE_INPUT] ); 

        read(fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT], &a, sizeof(a)); 
        printf("Child reads value %d from a \n", a); 

        read(fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT], &b, sizeof(b)); 
        printf("Child reads value %d from b \n", b); 

        read(fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT], &c, sizeof(c)); 
        printf("Child reads value %d from c \n", c); 

        read(fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT], &x, sizeof(x)); 
        printf("Child reads value %d from x \n", x); 
        r = a * x * x + b * x + c; 
        printf("x is %d\n", x); 
        printf("r is %d\n", r); 

        write(fd_toParent[PIPE_OUTPUT], &r, sizeof(r)); 
        fprintf(stdout, "%*sChild is all done\n", 0, ""); 

        close( fd_toChild[PIPE_INPUT] ); 
        close( fd_toParent[PIPE_OUTPUT] );
    } 

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```